# How can I include a unicode country flag in a TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unicode

I want to include country flags in some `TextView`s in my Android app.

These are being set via `setText` as follows:

```
viewBinding.lAe.setText(getString(R.string.flag_ae).concat(" ").concat("UAE"));
```

`flag_ae` is defined in my `strings.xml` currently as follows:

```
<string name="flag_ae" translatable="false">\u1F1E6\u1F1EA</string>
```

but my app displays "6 A UAE". What I want is " UAE".

I have also tried with the string defined as:

```
<string name="flag_ae" translatable="false">&#127462;&#127466;</string>
```

and also pasting the unicode character from a web page (as pasted into this question) into the string definition as below, but in this case all I get displayed in my app is "   UAE".

```
<string name="flag_ae" translatable="false"></string>
```

Note that in Android Studio the above displays as the special joined AE character rather than the flag as shown in this question.

Android obviously supports these flag characters somewheer as they display in SMS etc, so why not in my app... am I defining the string incorrectly? Can this be done directly in the Java rather than using a string resource?

I have tried the following directly in the Java (which is a copy and paste of the flag character used in this question, but again I get "   UAE" displayed in the app.

```
viewBinding.lAe.setText("\uD83C\uDDE6\uD83C\uDDEA".concat(" ").concat("UAE"));
```

Comment: Check this class: https://gist.github.com/BurakDizlek/9eb54a0245a765dbdd312148f1c96d7f

Comment: @SlothCoding I'm still just getting a blank character in the TextView using that class...

Comment: Based on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat I'm guessing my issue could be API version related and may mean I need to use emojiCompat... But I think that is probably too much of an overhead for my use case.

Comment: I now have that BurakDizlek class working. There were two issues - Android version (this only works with Marshmallow and above) and also the `X` character is missing from the code so Mexico wasn't working. If you add X in sequence to the Static Strings and the Switch clause it works perfectly.

Comment: BurakDizlek has now updated his class to include the `X` character, so all is good now direct from the GitHub download.

Comment: And the Kotlin version of the Java CountryFlags class above:
https://gist.github.com/cyb3rko/3aeadc9efd191330601ed1939810cf7c